# Simple ray tracing tutorial?

Tags: c#, math, 3d, matrix, raytracing

Years ago at uni I wrote a ray tracer in C++, but now I can hardly remember any of it. Just for fun, I decided to try writing a ray tracer again, this time in C#. But sadly I'm struggling getting started with the translation from camera coordinates to world coordinates.

Can anyone recommend me a good set of tutorials on writing a ray tracer from scratch? My maths knowledge is pretty basic, so I need to re-learn the matrix multiplication involved in working out where a point on the screen is in 3D space to cast a ray through it.

The intersection with shapes and shading parts I think I can work out, but I need to go back to basics for the camera translation.

Thanks!

Comment: How about [this](http://www.devmaster.net/articles/raytracing_series/part1.php)?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362140/literature-and-tutorials-for-writing-a-ray-tracer

Comment: Loving the silent downvote on a 6 year old question :P

Comment: In addition to all the answers, there's also Peter Shirley's "Ray Tracing in One Weekend" in PDF here: http://www.realtimerendering.com/raytracing/Ray%20Tracing%20in%20a%20Weekend.pdf and github here: https://github.com/petershirley/raytracinginoneweekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/raytrace/rtrace0.htm useful. It doesn't go all the way back to the basics but may still help (hint: if you see a broken font character as I do, it's meant to be a dot product).

Answer (score 2):

I made a very simple ray tracer, if you want to have a look at a c++ code sample here is the link. [a tiny ray tracer project](http://www.hevi.info/2010/05/a-tiny-ray-tracer-project/)

Answer (score 1):

Not an online-tutorial, but the book [Ray Tracing from the Ground Up](http://www.raytracegroundup.com/) by Kevin Suffern is very detailed.

Comment: Kevin Suffern was my lecturer at uni (a while back now). So I was trying to re-create the matrix multiplication he gave us during the course without simply copying it but not understanding it. I got in contact with him and it turns out he now uses orthonormal bases to do the camera conversion. I've got my tracer working using this technique now, and it's a lot less code than the matrix multiplication, though essentially doing the same thing.